# Concatenating objects to use for a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, concatenation

This seems like it should be simple but I have been working on this and am still stumped. [Here is a Codepen link to what I have so far.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNZyvY?editors=1010)

I need to allow the user select a data set (via a button) and then add that data set to whatever other data sets have already been selected up to that time, there would not be more than 3 or 4 data sets. My code right now looks like this:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="createDataSet(data1);">Add Data 1</button>
<button onclick="createDataSet(data2);">Add Data 2</button>

<button onclick="makeChart();">Make Chart</button>
```

JS:

```
var data1 = [{...},{...}];
var data2 = [{...},{...}];

// function is supposed to create a new concatenated dataset 
function createDataSet(data) {
  var dataSet = [];
  dataSet = dataSet.push(data);
  console.log(dataSet);
  return dataSet;
};

function makeChart(chartData){
  LoadChart(chartData);
}

// will make the following functional later
function LoadChart(){
  console.log("chart is made");
}
```

I have tried using concat() for this like the following:

```
function createDataSet(data) {
  var temp = [];
  var dataSet = [];
  temp = dataSet.concat(data);
  console.log(temp);
  return dataSet;
};
```

but that didn't work as well, I expect my approach is fundamentally flawed somehow right now. [Again, here is a Codepen link to what I have so far.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNZyvY?editors=1010)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to concatenate arrays to the array variable `dataSet`:

```js
var data1 = [{"fake": 2132,"data": 2676,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 2132,"data": 2676,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 2132,"data": 2676,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 2132,"data": 2676,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 2132,"data": 2676,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 2132,"data": 2676,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 2132,"data": 2676,"example": "human"}],
    data2 = [{"fake": 32,"data": 76,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 32,"data": 76,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 32,"data": 76,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 32,"data": 76,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 32,"data": 76,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 32,"data": 76,"example": "human"}, {"fake": 32,"data": 76,"example": "human"}],
    dataSet = [];

function createDataSet(data) {
  dataSet = dataSet.concat(data);
}

function makeChart(dataSet){
  console.log(dataSet);
  LoadChart(dataSet);
}

// will make the following functional later
function LoadChart(){
  console.log("chart is made");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createDataSet(data1);">Add Data 1</button>
<button onclick="createDataSet(data2);">Add Data 2</button>

<button onclick="makeChart(dataSet);">Make Chart</button>
```

Comment: I have checked the link and receive http 404